# Upsert that always inserts but conditionally updates?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a DB for a bit of a game and I have a leader board. When a user generates a particular score and they're not in the table, I want to add them to the table, however if they're already in the table, I only want to update the score if their new score is lower than their old score (like golf, lower is better). The table has 3 columns: Name, Value, and EntryTime. Name is the KEY.

Currently I'm upserting unconditionally with

```
INSERT INTO BasicEntries (Name, Value, EntryTime) VALUES (@name, @score, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Value` = @score, `EntryTime` = NOW();
```

I've tried adding a `WHERE` onto the end but I keep getting back an error about my SQL syntax. I could split the logic up into a `SELECT` that determines if the username already exists and then either `UPDATE` or `INSERT` from there, but I'm curious as to what a one-liner for this problem would look like.

How can I modify the above line so that it continues to `INSERT` when the Name isn't already in the table but will only `UPDATE` if `@score` is less than the existing `Value`?

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` is not allowed on `UPDATE` statements in `MySQL`. However you can use `IF`.

You an do something like:

```
INSERT INTO table
 A=aa, 
 B=bb, 
 C=cc 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 A = IF( D = dd, aa, A),
 B = IF( D = dd, bb, B),
 C = IF( D = dd, cc, C)
```

Check the link:
[Control Flow Funtions - If](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Answer (score 0):

This means for you:

```
INSERT INTO BasicEntries (Name, Value, EntryTime)
VALUES (@name, @score, NOW()) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  `EntryTime` = if(@score > value, NOW(), EntryTime), 
  `Value` = if(@score > value, NOW(),EntryTime)
;
```